# 1-D Heat difusion in python

Tags: python, math, physics

I am attempting to compare the analytical and numerical solutions for heat diffusion in a rod using or infinity wall Python. The equation I'm working with is as follows:

T_i^(i+1) = T_i^(i) * (1 - 2 * r) + r * (T_{i+1}^(i) + T_{i-1}^(i))
where r = α * Δt / Δx^2.

The analytical solution I'm trying to compare with is given by:

T(x, t) = T_1 + (T_0 - T_1) * (4 / π) * Σ_(n=1)^(∞) (1 / n) * e^(-n * π * α * t / (2 * L)) * sin(n * π * x / (2 * L))
Here are the parameters I'm using:

Number of points (N): 20

Length of the rod (L): 1 m

Number of time steps (t): 300

Diffusion coefficient (α): 0.001

Spatial step size (Δx): L / N

Time step size (Δt): 1

Right wall temperature: 100°C

I've implemented both the finite difference method and the analytical solution in Python, and I'm attempting to create an animation to compare the temperature distributions over time. However, the two solutions do not match, and I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly implement the analytical solution and compare it with the numerical solution.

Here's the Python code I've written so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

N = 20  # Number of points
L = 1   # Length of the rod (m)
t = 300  # Number of time steps

a = 0.001
dx = L / N
dt = 1

r = (a * dt) / dx**2

print('Convergence factor is: {:.4f} < 0.5'.format(r))

# Initialize arrays for numerical and analytical solutions
T = np.zeros((t, N))
T_analytical = np.zeros((t, N))
x = np.linspace(0, L, N)

T[:, 0] = 100

for k in range(t - 1):
    for i in range(1, N - 1):
        T[k + 1, i] = T[k][i] * (1 - 2 * r) + r * (T[k][i + 1] + T[k][i - 1])
    
    for n in range(1, 200, 2):
      T_analytical[k] += (400 / np.pi) * (1 / n) * np.exp(- a * k * ((n * np.pi)/ (2 * L))**2 ) * np.sin((n * np.pi * x) / 2 * L)
    T_analytical[k] = 100 - T_analytical[k]

# Create the animation
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, L)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax.set_xlabel('Position')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2, color='red')
line_analytical, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2, color='blue')

def update(frame):
    y_numerical = T[frame]
    y_analytical = T_analytical[frame]
    line.set_data(x, y_numerical)
    line_analytical.set_data(x, y_analytical)
    ax.set_title(f'Time in seconds: {frame}')
    return line, line_analytical

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=t, interval=100, blit=True)
ani.save('heat_diffusion_comparison.gif', writer='pillow', fps=10)
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly compare these two solutions and troubleshoot the discrepancies I'm encountering. Thank you!

[Graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TL8i.png)

Comment: Felipe, looks like you've made a good start. Problems like this can only be debugged by looking at the details. My advice is to simplify the program by removing the code for constructing the animation and any other stuff not directly related to the calculations. Reduce the number of intervals from 300 to, say, 3, and print out the solution array and any other intermediate results at each step of the iteration. Check the solution to verify it satisfies the laws of physics -- do you find that the heat transfer through the boundaries satisfies conservation of energy? Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Could you please check again the exponential term in the analytical solution? That should be the time dependence but it's missing a `dt` and it's not dimensionally correct, there should be squared distance at the denominator, `L**2` or `L * x`?

Comment: It was missing an exponent, dt = 1 but thanks for all the help @kikon